# Convert an array into an array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

This might be an easy one but I'm struggling to get it done.

I have this following array in php which I want to json_encode as an array of objects. What's the best way of doing this in php?

```
Array
(
    [6946] => Array
        (
            [AssetGroupName] => Computer
            [AssetGroupID] => 14
        )

    [6945] => Array
        (
            [AssetGroupName] => Laptop
            [AssetGroupID] => 15
        )
)
```

Json output I'm trying to get.

```
{ 
   "data": [
      {
         "AssetGroupName": "Computer",
         "AssetGroupID": "12"
      },
      {
         "AssetGroupName": "Laptop",
         "AssetGroupID": "15"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: `json_encode()` will encode an associative array as a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's relatively simple, first, you need to create the proper array in PHP with nested `data` subarray then just to get rid of keys (or in the other order it's up to you). When using numeric keys that are not starting from 0 and increased by 1 they are just considered as keys in an associative array.

```php
$array = [
    'data' => [
        6946 => [
            'AssetGroupName' => 'Computer',
            'AssetGroupID'   => 14
        ],

        6945 => [
            'AssetGroupName' => 'Laptop',
            'AssetGroupID'   => 15
        ]
    ]
];

$array['data'] = array_values($array['data']);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Using `array_values` did the trick. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
> $array = [
>     ['AssetGroupName' => 'computer', 'AssetGroupID' => 14], ];
> 
> echo json_encode(['data' => $array]);
```

Comment: I can bet, that OP didn't want to rewrite arrays data manually to get rid of the keys.